# Passing multiple parameters in .bat file via user input does not display all of them correctly

Tags: batch-file, cmd, user-input

I have a test.bat file which has only this statement

echo  'ABC\%1%\DEF\%2%'

I am calling the same from cmd as test.bat 400 500 
And it prints ABC4002

What it is doing is , it is taking the first input parameter  - 400 and substituting it correctly and then directly prints 2 which is actually the '2' of %2% 
How do I echo it to print it correctly ?

Comment: To expand and parameter use `÷n` not `÷n÷`„ thats all

Comment: Effectively there's no variable named `%\DEF\%`, and a trailing `%` in a batch file is discarded.

Comment: _I suppose it's also a perfect example to show why environment variables should never begin with numeric digits._

Comment: jeb's answer doesn't look like it formatted correctly.  I believe you want `echo 'ABC\%1\DEF\%2'`.  If not, then please post what you want the output to be.

Comment: @avery_larry You're right, my mobile phone hasn't used the correct `%` character. It should be read `%n` vs `%n%`

Comment: @jeb's answer worked. I can echo ABCE400DEF500.